# After submitting job to Spark ,Getting version `GLIBC_2.25' not found Error

Tags: python, apache-spark

we are running spark job but is is failing with below error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o989.checkpoint.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 382 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 382.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 63, ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal, executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
  venv/bin/python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by venv/bin/python)
```

how to fix this ?
as we already have Glibc 2.26 installed